# Flutter: Show Draggable Bottom Sheet Without Blocking UI Elements in the Background

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable, bottom-sheet

I am trying to create a workflow by which when a user presses a button, a draggable bottom sheet will appear with more controls but will still allow the user to interact with the controls in the background.

The default bottom sheet is not draggable and I also tried adding a DraggableScrollableSheet but then the background controls gets blocked.

How can I implement this workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the bottom sheet with a `gestureDetector` and set its behaviour to translucent.

```
GestureDetector(
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
child: 
)
```

Not sure if this works on alert or bottom sheet. Please let me know if it worked